# Java - Regular Expressions matching one to another

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to retrieve bits of data using RE. Problem is I'm not very fluent with RE. Consider the code.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

class HTTP{

    private static String getServer(httpresp){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\bServer)(.*[Server:-\r\n]"); //What RE syntax do I use here?
        Matcher m = p.matcher(httpresp);

        if (m.find()){
            return m.group(2);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String testdata = "HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nServer: Apache\r\n\r\n"; //Test data

        System.out.println(getServer(testdata));
```

How would I get "Server:" to the next "\r\n" out which would output "Apache"? I googled around and tried myself, but have failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use capturing groups or positive lookbehind.

```
Pattern.compile("(?:\\bServer:\\s*)(.*?)(?=[\r\n]+)");
```

Then print the group index 1.

**Example:**

```
String testdata = "HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\nServer: Apache\r\n\r\n";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?:\\bServer:\\s*)(.*?)(?=[\r\n]+)").matcher(testdata);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

OR

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?:\\bServer\\b\\S*\\s+)(.*?)(?=[\r\n]+)").matcher(testdata);
if (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
Apache
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?:\\bServer:\\s*)`  In regex, non-capturing group would be represented as `(?:...)`, which will do matching only. `\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character. `Server:` matches the string `Server:` and the following zero or more spaces would be matched by `\s*`
- `(.*?)` In regex `(..)` called capturing group which captures those characters which are matched by the pattern present inside the capturing group. In our case `(.*?)` will capture all the characters non-greedily upto,
- `(?=[\r\n]+)` one or more line breaks are detected. `(?=...)` called positive lookahead which asserts that the match must be followed by the characters which are matched by the pattern present inside the lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

It's a one liner:

```
private static String getServer(httpresp) {
    return httpresp.replaceAll(".*Server: (.*?)\r\n.*", "$1");
}
```

The trick here is two-part:

- use `.*?`, which is a reluctant match (consumes as little as possible and still match)
- regex matches whole input, but desired target captured and returned using a back reference